# Unknown Serialized Object to XML

Tags: java, xml, serialization, base64

I'm trying to figure out if it's somehow possible to convert a base 64 encoded serialized object to XML without having the class available. I coded an example below where I created a car class, created a car object, serialized the object and encoded to string. I comment out the car class and attempt to decode/deserialize but obviously this throws a "ClassNotFoundException" from serialization utils. Any help would be appreciated and I'm open to external libraries.

**How can I convert a base64 encoded, serialized object ("s" from below), to XML of the object?**

```
public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
//        Car car = new Car("black","honda","accord","I2");
//        byte[] carByte = SerializationUtils.serialize(car);
//        String s = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(carByte); // returns text below
        // Created from commented code above
        String s = "rO0ABXNyAAhNYWluJENhcjrcX+tC1QS+AgAETAAFY29sb3J0ABJMamF2YS9sYW5nL1N0cmluZztMAAZlbmdpbmVxAH4AAUwABG1ha2VxAH4AAUwABW1vZGVscQB+AAF4cHQABWJsYWNrdAACSTJ0AAVob25kYXQABmFjY29yZA==";
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(Base64.getDecoder().decode(s));
        //ideally below would print xml
        System.out.println(SerializationUtils.deserialize(Base64.getDecoder().decode(s)).toString());

    }

//    public static class Car implements Serializable {
//        String color;
//        String make;
//        String model;
//        String engine;
//
//        public Car(String color, String make, String model, String engine) {
//            this.color = color;
//            this.make = make;
//            this.model = model;
//            this.engine = engine;
//        }
//
//        public String getColor() {
//            return color;
//        }
//
//        public void setColor(String color) {
//            this.color = color;
//        }
//
//        public String getMake() {
//            return make;
//        }
//
//        public void setMake(String make) {
//            this.make = make;
//        }
//
//        public String getModel() {
//            return model;
//        }
//
//        public void setModel(String model) {
//            this.model = model;
//        }
//
//        public String getEngine() {
//            return engine;
//        }
//
//        public void setEngine(String engine) {
//            this.engine = engine;
//        }
//    }
}
```

Comment: Without the class available, you'd have to reverse engineer the Java serialization protocol, and read the individual fields of the class yourself, then write them as XML.  If you have the class to begin with, and you can write to XML instead of Java's serialized format, use `XMLEncoder`.

Comment: You have binary serialized data. You would have to use Reflection methods.  Maybe following will help : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binary-serialization